# 2006 Harley Davidson bogs down when I attempt to ride or accelerate

Tags: engine, motorcycle, harley-davidson

I just finished installing a new clutch, and cleaning the carb and I took apart the front jug. I’ve put it all back together and adjusted the clutch, that works properly, and check for compression and spark, those are good but I’ve installed a new petcock on the tank and new filter, as well as a carb rebuild and new air filter and new plugs.

The problem I’m having is that when I start the bike and let it idle it functions fine, I can even rev the engine with no problems, but when I put it in gear and attempt to ride down the road it loses power and will barley stay running when I crank the throttle past a quarter turn. Then it will bogg down sometimes if you crank the throttle to full it will pick back up and you’ll be able to accelerate but it doesn’t feel right any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Its a fuel delivery issue, recheck your work, verify there is good fuel supply (flow) to the carb(s).

Comment: What happens if you pull the clutch in while it's bogging? I feel like there's an issue with the clutch. Was a Break-In Procedure Recommended/Performed?

Comment: It won’t throttle up in neutral anymore an feels like it’s running rich now I’ve taken the air filter off and it’s shooting fuel in when you crack the throttle the slide moves up and down all the vacuum lines are hooked up I don’t see any issues but no break in procedure was performed but the clutch feels like it’s grabing and disengaging fine

Answer (score 1):

Is Air vent for carburetor bowl clogged, blocked, need vent screw pulled out?
S&S carburetor with after market air filter require a screw to be pulled out other wise you have this problem.